# sql mysql mathemetics

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a problem of mathematics and sql, please help me solve this:
I'm numbering these steps to clear this problem of mine.

1. I need to query all records that include conditions based on timestamp (column: time1, time1 has data type of **timestamp**), I usually query like this way:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A 
WHERE
    ( time1 >= DATE( SYSDATE() ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
    AND
    ( time1 < DATE( SYSDATE() ) );
```

Output:

```
1   zzzz1   1
2   zzzz2   2
3   zzzz3   3
4   zzzz4   4
5   zzzz5   5
```

2. This is my query from table A (now column: time has data type of `INT`):

```
SELECT time from A limit 5;
```

Output:

```
1604299478649
1604299479395
1604299487604
1604299493870
1604299493895
```

3. I want to change to another `SELECT` statement but the OUTPUT result doesn't change. For example, the period of time is: `[00:00:00 05/11/2023 ; 00:00:00 06/11/2023)`. The SELECT statement below is my idea:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A 
WHERE
    ( time1 >= ( DATE( SYSDATE() ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) * 24 * 3600 * 1000 )
    AND
    ( time1 < DATE( SYSDATE() ) * 24 * 3600 * 1000 );
```

But I think it must have another way easier, I need helps.

Thanks a lot for help!

I have a problem of mathematics and sql, please help me solve this. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: ...this has nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but a useless repetition of the tag information. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that its content is clear to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask]. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Comment: If these are time/date fields, why don't you change the column to a date/time type?  Then you can use the extensive MySQL date functions.

Comment: Your question is not clear (to me, at least) but I believe you want a query where the criteria is the last 24 hour period but according to column **time** (whose data type is `int`) rather than column **time1**. Hence you are asking how to convert a timestamp to an `int`, correct?

Comment: Why are you multiplying a date by the number of seconds in a day? What is the datatype of `time1`? What is working and not working?

Comment: @Bohemian time1 is a timestamp, but time is a INT data type.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: How about this way guys? I just found it.                                                            
                                                                                                                             
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE (time >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 DAY)) )*1000) ) and (time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(SYSDATE()))*1000));

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the same post. Also, please add all clarification to your post, not to the comment section